# Automatically displaying images/PDF on a screen

Tags: pdf, images, pdf-viewer, image-viewer

Is there some sort of application that displays specific files like PDF and/or images from a specified folder onto a screen? I have software that automatically drops images and PDF or client's orders into a folder, and I would like these to automatically display onto a screen, preferably even PDF files with multiple pages(for example display the one page on one screen and the other page on another)

**It's very important this software always displays the file correctly after it's been altered** so that the information on the screens is always up to date.

Is there anything that can provide this for me?

Answer (score 1):

If this is an essential business function, I wouldn't trust a program to automatically display a changed file. Indeed, by displaying a file, the application might *lock* it so that it cannot subsequently be updated!

Better might be to display an alert on any changes to files in the folder(s), to let a user open and review the change, and then have the user *close* the viewer to allow changes to the file. There are numerous [tools to watch a folder](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/3-portable-tools-monitor-files-folders-changes/) and create notifications of changes.